# NoClassDefFoundError after Restart programmatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, noclassdeffounderror

I had this class, which work as it designed, if I started the spring boot app normally.

```
public class ComboBoxHelper {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ComboBoxHelper.class);
private static final I18NProvider i18nProvider = Application.getAppContext().getBean(I18NProvider.class);

public ComboBoxHelper() {
    // To do something
}

public ItemLabelGenerator<DocumentTypes> startItemLabelGenerator() {
    return new ItemLabelGenerator<DocumentTypes>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -338940206315118937L;

        @Override
        public String apply(DocumentTypes item) {
            logger.debug("====> ItemLabelGenerator - {} <====", item);
            String itemValue = "";
            if (item.getTypeName().contains("common.string")) {
                itemValue = i18nProvider.getTranslation(item.getTypeName(), UI.getCurrent().getLocale());
            } else {
                itemValue = item.getTypeName();
            }
            return itemValue;
        }
    };
}
```

}

If I started the spring boot app with this method over a button:

```
    public static void restart() {
    ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();
        context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
    });

    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```

I get the error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class** at the point where I initialize the ComboBoxHelper class. Why work it if I started the spring boot app normally with the java command and not over my button restart ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: [Why did you not think it important to post the stack trace?](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)

Comment: Here's a guess: `Application.getAppContext()`  is returning `null` when you are initializing the `i18nProvider` field in `ComboBoxHelper` (perhaps it doesn't exist yet). Remember static initialization is on first reference (not including `import`), so it may be pertinent to either initialize this later, have a different way of retrieving some static info, or not have it as static (there's not really any huge cost to a non-static variable here if it references the same static resource).

Comment: Please update your question instead of "answering" it with new details. From the stacktrace I can say that Spring can't autowire your class. Is it annotated as @Component (or similar)? I can't see it in code.

Comment: In both versions of the class ComboBoxHelper only just missing the imports.